# How to sort a nested list by reverse length of the sublists and keep the original order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

Example:

```
a = 
[
[['test', 21, 28], ['test', 61, 68], ['test', 111, 118], ['test', 118, 125]],
[['Columns', 21, 28], ['Columns', 61, 68], ['Columns', 111, 118], ['Columns', 118, 125], ['Columns', 128, 135]], 
[['Delete', 14, 20], ['Delete', 47, 53], ['Delete', 54, 60], ['Delete', 78, 84], ['Delete', 95, 101]], 
[['rw', 21, 28], ['rw', 61, 68], ['rw', 111, 118]]
]
```

What I want to do is to sort the nested list by reversed length of the sublists
but to keep the original order if the length of sublists is the same.

Expected result:

```
[
[['Columns', 21, 28], ['Columns', 61, 68], ['Columns', 111, 118], ['Columns', 118, 125], ['Columns', 128, 135]], 
[['Delete', 14, 20], ['Delete', 47, 53], ['Delete', 54, 60], ['Delete', 78, 84], ['Delete', 95, 101]], 
[['test', 21, 28], ['test', 61, 68], ['test', 111, 118], ['test', 118, 125]], 
[['rw', 21, 28], ['rw', 61, 68], ['rw', 111, 118]]
]
```

I know I can use this to sort the list by reverse length but it will not keep the original order:

```
a = sorted(a, key=len, reverse=True)
```

(it reverses the sublists 'Delete' and 'Columns')

How can I sort the list by reverse length of the sublists and keep the original order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TimSort is a stable sort, so it normally preserves the order of equal items. So your code *should* work correctly.

Alternatively, get rid of the `reverse=True` and use a key function that returns the negative of the sublist length.

```
a = [
    [['test', 21, 28], ['test', 61, 68], ['test', 111, 118], ['test', 118, 125]],
    [['Columns', 21, 28], ['Columns', 61, 68], ['Columns', 111, 118], ['Columns', 118, 125], ['Columns', 128, 135]],    
    [['Delete', 14, 20], ['Delete', 47, 53], ['Delete', 54, 60], ['Delete', 78, 84], ['Delete', 95, 101]], 
    [['rw', 21, 28], ['rw', 61, 68], ['rw', 111, 118]]
]

a.sort(key=lambda x: -len(x))
for row in a:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
[['Columns', 21, 28], ['Columns', 61, 68], ['Columns', 111, 118], ['Columns', 118, 125], ['Columns', 128, 135]]
[['Delete', 14, 20], ['Delete', 47, 53], ['Delete', 54, 60], ['Delete', 78, 84], ['Delete', 95, 101]]
[['test', 21, 28], ['test', 61, 68], ['test', 111, 118], ['test', 118, 125]]
[['rw', 21, 28], ['rw', 61, 68], ['rw', 111, 118]]
```

If I use

```
a.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
```

I get the same output as above. If you don't get that output too, something *very* weird is going on. Note that this version is more efficient than the version above, since it calls `len` directly (which is implemented in C and it does a fast attribute lookup to determine the object's length), and Python function calls are relatively slow, whether they are `def` functions or `lambda`s.

---

BTW, when you want to sort a list in-place you should always call its `.sort` method. The built-in `sorted` function actually creates a new list, copies the original data to that list, and then calls `.sort` on it, and then binds the new list to the destination. So it's much more efficient to avoid creating that copy and call `.sort` yourself on the original list.

Comment: the `reverse` keyword really affects stability of the sort? the documentation states that `The reverse parameter still maintains sort stability (so that records with equal keys retain the original order)` - in "Odd and Ends" at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto

Comment: I think @ewcz is correct, e.g. `sorted(['a', 'b'], key=len) == sorted(['a', 'b'], key=len, reverse=True)`

Comment: @ewcz Hey, you're right!  I should've tested the OP's code :oops:

Comment: @PM2Ring no problem, I was also confused about what the OP actually wants :) - or perhaps she/he is using some ancient Python, I read somewhere that the sort is supposed to be stable as of `2.4`

Comment: @Chris_Rands I've updated my answer. I almost deleted it, but I figure it has _some_ value...

Comment: @ewcz Even earlier than that. [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort): "Timsort has been Python's standard sorting algorithm since version 2.3." FWIW, the author, Tim Peters, is still active on SO. He commented on a question I answered a week or so ago.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks, I was also confused, you'll keep my upvote!

Comment: Yes! Thanks. I know what I did wrong.. I did this: `sorted(a, key=lambda x: (len(x), x[1]), reverse=True)` - reverse sort and than a sort of the 2nd element of every sublist.